# How to disable spring session when store-type removed from ver3.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-session

I noticed that in order to disable spring session, the configuration property `spring.session.store-type` can be set to `none`.

However, the property has been removed ([ref](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/27756)).

Thus, may I know how it can be disabled in the new version now?

Answer (score 0):

If you want Spring Boot to back off and you want to have control over Spring Session configuration, you can use `@Enable*HttpSession` as mentioned in [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.spring-session):

> You can take control over Spring Session’s configuration using `@Enable*HttpSession` (servlet) or `@Enable*WebSession` (reactive).
> This will cause the auto-configuration to back off.
> Spring Session can then be configured using the annotation’s attributes rather than the previously described configuration properties.

You can use the annotation in combination with `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation from Spring Boot.

Another solution is to use the [Testcontainers support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.testcontainers) or [Docker Compose support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.docker-compose) so you have the same setup in both dev/prod.

Related:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/2459